# Rails Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: interest_ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Im working with a multistep form (using Wicked gem). In the first couple steps of the form i am editing the user model and those steps work fine.. Then I attempt the "interests" model which has a HABTM relationship with the user model. However i get this error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UserStepsController#update

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: interest_ids
Rails.root: /Users/nelsonkeating/rails_projects/Oreminder1

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/user_steps_controller.rb:12:in `update'
```

user_steps_controller.rb

```
 class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :standard, :personal, :interests, :dates 

 def show
   @user = current_user
   render_wizard
 end

 def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.attributes = params[:user]
 render_wizard @user
end

end
```

Heres the view:

```
<%= render layout: 'form' do |f| %>

<% for interest in Interest.find(:all) %>
 <label class="checkbox">
  <%= check_box_tag "user[interest_ids][]", interest.id, @user.interests.include?(interest) %>
  <%= interest.name %>
 </label>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you're in Rails 3.2.3 or newer, you now have to explicitly white list anything you want to mass assign to. Could that be the issue? See http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Rails-3-2-3-makes-mass-assignment-change-1498547.html .

Comment: I have it set in my interests model: 
    attr_accessible :name, :interest_ids

Comment: It should be set in your user model.

Comment: Well there's your problem, then. The interest_ids setter is on the User model, so that's where you need to white list it. Mischa beat me to it on answering, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get rid of this error by adding this to your user model:

```
attr_accessible :interest_ids
```

Without this the `interest_ids` attribute is protected against [mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/security.html#mass-assignment) and when you try to assign values to it anyway an exception is thrown.